# What does this book mean when it says this function is "immeadiatly integrable by inspection"?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I'm reading a book where the author is deriving the one-dimensional wave equation. At this point, he arrived at the formula
$$\frac{\partial^2y }{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{c²}\cdot\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2} $$ Where $y=y(x,t)$.

He then proceeded to define variable substitutions
$$x=\frac{v-u}{2}$$
$$y=\frac{v+u}{2}$$

The author then uses these substitutions to get the following expression
$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial u\partial v}=-\frac{1}{4}\left\{ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2} \right\}$$

and obviously, this implies that
$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial u\partial v}=0$$

Finally he concludes, and I quote: "This equation is now immediately integrable, *by inspection* (which is the reason for the change of variables from x and t to u and v!), to give
$$y(u.v)=\Phi(u)+\Psi(v)"$$

I don't understand this last step. How was the change of variables useful? What does he mean "immediately integrable by inspection"? Can someone provide me with some extra details and maybe a thorough explanation for this step, as if I were 5?

Comment: Do you know what the solutions of $\partial y/\partial u = 0$ look like (assuming the function is smooth on the entire plane, say)?

Comment: What happens when you differentiate $y(u,v)$ twice, once with respect to each variable?

Comment: @TedShifrin it's a plane. Is there anything super simple and obvious here that I just can't see?

Comment: No, its graph is most definitely not necessarily a plane. Go back to one variable for a minute. If $y=f(x)$ and $dy/dx = 0$ on all of the real numbers, what do you know about the function $f$?

Comment: Integrate with respect to one variable, then the other.

Comment: @TedShifrin it's just a constant, doesn't change. I mean, it doesn't change with respect to u -- not a plane no. I'm tired.

Comment: @mjw what? I don't get it...

Comment: Anyway, more to the point.  The advice given here in the comments by others will lead you to the answer.  You may need to work to understand it.  Basically, when the derivative with respect to a variable is zero, the function is "constant" relative to that variable.  Thus $\Phi(u)$ is constant with respect to $v$ (does not depend on $v$), etc.

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{\partial{\Phi(u)}}{\partial v} = 0. \quad \displaystyle \frac{\partial{[\Phi(u)+ \Psi(v)]}}{\partial v} = \Psi^\prime(v).$

Comment: @mjw ah, I see! Right, of course. But to get to the conclusion I must assume that $\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial u\partial v}=\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial v \partial u}$, otherwise, I cannot conclude that y is composed by those 2 functions, right?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 y }{\partial u \partial v}=\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial v \partial u}?$  Is that the question?

Comment: @mjw, yes, sorry, I edited the comment.

Comment: I don't think you need that assumption *a priori*.  It does hold true simply because order of differentiation does not matter for this family of functions.